# Creating works fine but Updating fails when using exactly same entity and form

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

Example below works fine when I try to **create** a new `car` in database. If I leave `brands` select box **blank** in the webform, I get "*The Brand field is required*" error after submitting which is perfectly fine and as expected.

**Problem:**

If I repeat exactly same steps like described above when trying to **update** a selected record, I should still get "The Brand field is required" error after submitting, instead I'm getting "`ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Car\BrandBundle\Entity\Cars::setBrands() must be an instance of Car\BrandBundle\Entity\Brands, null given, called in .... line on public function setBrands(\Car\BrandBundle\Entity\Brands $brands)`"

Any reason why or any solution?

**CAR UPDATE CONTROLLER (DOESN'T WORK)**

```
private function getForm($car, $id)
{
    return $this->createForm(new CarsType(), $car,
        array('action' => $this->generateUrl('cars_independent_update_process',
            array('id' => $id))));
}

public function processAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CarBrandBundle:Cars');
    $car = $repo->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));

    if (! $car) 
    {
        return new Response('There is no such car in database');
    }

    $form = $this->getForm($car, $id);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid() !== true)
    {
        return $this->render('CarBrandBundle:Independent:cars_update.html.twig',
            array('page' => 'Cars Update Independent', 'form' => $form->createView()));
    }

    exit('FINE');
}
```

**CAR CREATE CONTROLLER (WORKS FINE)**

```
class CarsCreateController extends Controller
{
    private function getForm()
    {
        return $this->createForm(new CarsType(), new Cars(),
                array('action' => $this->generateUrl('cars_independent_create_process')));
    }

    public function processAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid() !== true)
        {
            return $this->render('CarBrandBundle:Independent:cars_update.html.twig',
            array('page' => 'Cars Update Independent', 'form' => $form->createView()));
        }

    exit('FINE');
}
```

**ENTITY**

```
class Cars
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brands", inversedBy="cars")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brands_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The Brand field is required.")
     */
    protected $brands;

    /**
     * @param \Car\BrandBundle\Entity\Brands $brands
     */
    public function setBrands(\Car\BrandBundle\Entity\Brands $brands)
    {
        $this->brands = $brands;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Car\BrandBundle\Entity\Brands
     */
    public function getBrands()
    {
        return $this->brands;
    }
}
```

**FORM TYPE**

```
class CarsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setAction($options['action'])
            ->setMethod('POST')

            ->add('brands', 'entity',
                array(
                    'error_bubbling' => true,
                    'class' => 'CarBrandBundle:Brands',
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'expanded' => false,
                    'empty_value' => '',
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repo)
                                        {
                                            return $repo->createQueryBuilder('b')
                                                        ->orderBy('b.name', 'ASC');
                                        }
                ))

            ->add('model', 'text', array('label' => 'Model', 'error_bubbling' => true))
            ->add('year', 'date', array('label' => 'Year', 'error_bubbling' => true))
            ->add('button', 'submit', array('label' => 'Submit'))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'Car\BrandBundle\Entity\Cars'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'cars';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was related to Constraint so I added it to the class and it work fine now.

```
/**
 * Class Cars
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="cars", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"model", "brands_id"})})
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"model","brands"}, message="The Model and the Brand combination already exists in database.")
 */
class Cars
{

    /**
     * @var object
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brands", inversedBy="cars")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brands_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The Brand field is required.")
     */
    protected $brands;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your update version you don't transmit the id when you generate your route for the form action. Will be something like that :

```
private function getForm($car)
{
    return $this->createForm(new CarsType(), $car,
        array('action' => $this->generateUrl('cars_independent_update_process', array('id' => $car->getId()))));
}
```

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake. It is actually there. I updated the OP above.